# how to run a 3rd party exe during a windows installer installation (using setup and deployment project)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-deployment

I have to package a `3rd party exe` with my `MSI`. So ideally the 3rd party exe should get installed first during MSI installation and then it should drop my project dlls.

I'm using a Visual studio setup and deployment project(2010) - Visual studio installer. Could someone tell me how to achieve this?

The 3rd party exe should get installed first when I run the MSI and then the other dlls in the MSI should get dropped in its location..

I tried to add the exe by going to `View` ->`customactions` .in the custom actions editor clicked on Install to add the exe and selected the exe.

then in properties window changed the property of `installer` class to  `false`.

But this isn't working..The 3rd party exe is not getting installed.could somebody pls help?

Comment: Trying adding the exe to custom action's ***Commit*** phase also. Did you check if the installation works when you manually run the exe ?

Comment: yes manually it works

Comment: Can you add the exe to Commit phase and check if it works ?

Comment: no.that din't help either.I could see the exe in the MSI location..that means it has got packaged..but not getting installed automatically.

Comment: Is there anything to do with the arguments? in the argument I could just see /Install

Comment: Yes, you have to give **/s** as argument.

Comment: I tried adding /s it din't work.so tried by removing the arguments itself(meaning I made it empty)..and tried to install through command prompt in admin mode. But it says already another installation is in progress when I click on the next button in 3rd party msi

Comment: Then the only option is to use a Installer class. You need to add an installer class to your solution and within the class you need to execute the exe through code.

Comment: I created a bootstrapper package for the 3rd party exe. after the build when I ran the setup.exe.it installed the 3rd party exe first and then the other file copying happens. Thanks all for your help and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a bootstrapper package for the 3rd party exe. after the build when I ran the setup.exe.it installed the 3rd party exe first and then the other file copying happens. Thanks all for your help and support. –